# Disable "is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer" in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macros, availability

The problem is I want to check a solution which requires a variable declared in a class. But if I do it I should mark the whole class as `@available(iOS 11.0, *)` which causes a lot of changes in many other places.

So is it possible to disable it fully in one place at best? Or disable it temporarily (just to test new features without of significant changes and without changes of the minimum iOS version) at worst?

Comment: If that's an obj-c class you could use `NSClassFromString` to determine if it's available at runtime.

Comment: it is swift and swift class

Comment: Fair enough. Still you can use `NSClassFromString` in `Swift` for `NSObject` subclasses. But not for pure `Swift` classes.

Comment: So you want to define a variable and mark it as being available only for iOS 11 or newer?

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Sulthan already got 2 similar solutions with properties. Look at them

Comment: @Ashley Mills @El Tomato @Hardik.T @Rob @bugs the question is posted and answered. What is unclear for you? How to add a single macro `@available(iOS 11.0, *)` without of refactoring the whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found is to use properties:

```
class SomeClass {
    private var _authSession: NSObject!;
    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    var authSession: SFAuthenticationSession! {
        get {
            return _authSession as! SFAuthenticationSession
        }
        set(val) {
            _authSession = val
        }
    }
}
```

It is just an example so `!` may be replaced with `?` if it is necessary. In short - iOS forbids to declare variables with `@available` but allows to mark properties with this macro.

Comment: only computed properties